# Vue: How to use v-model in post ApI

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have code below in vue js and I wanted to update data the model by using AddCategory and it works fine, on the other hand, I wanted to post this to API Url using the post data below, but when I set v-model="posts.AddCategory" it didn't work, is there a way to do it?

```html
<b-form-input
            id="input"
            type="text"
            name="AddCategory"
            v-model="AddCategory" //v-model="posts.AddCategory" didn't work
            placeholder="categories"
            required
          />
          <div
              class="categories"
              v-for="(category, index) in categories"
              :key="index"
              @click="Add(index, AddCategory)"
            >
              <mark> {{ category.category_name }} </mark>
              
              <script>

export default {
  name: "postComponent",
  components: {
    Editor: PrismEditor,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      selectedIndex: null,
      isediting: false,
      AddCategory: "",
      posts: {
        title: null,
        question: null,
        code: require("../example.js").default /* eslint-enable */,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    Add(AddCategory, index) {
      this.AddCategory = AddCategory;
      this.selectedIndex = index;
      this.isediting = true;
    },
```

Comment: I haven't tried this so this may or may not work, but it looks like you don't have a property in your posts object called AddCategory, but AddCategory is its own property in your data.Your posts object would need the propery AddCategory added.

Comment: i added this but it didn't work too

Comment: The value in this click method: `@click="Add(index, AddCategory)"` is the same as what you defined it as initially in `AddCategory: ''`, what are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: here what's done is a click method on category names so when i click it will be added to the input field above , now i need to use v-model to post to api url  but i can't figure out how to do it

Comment: AddCategory is a data property you're passing it (btw parameter order is wrong) to data, then even up itself. I guess it should be @click="Add(category, index)". To make v-model work, you need to add AddCategory into the posts object. v-model doesn't create keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your v-model=posts.AddCategory won't work as you are hitting one of the object caveats as defined in vue https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects.
What you can do is first in your Add method you could to so:

```
Add(category,index){
     this.$set(this.post,'AddCategory',category);
     .... 
}
```